# Java JFrame.setSize giving wrong size

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a window using the swing library in java.
Everything works fine, except for one minor (but very annoying) issue:

```
private void init()
    {
        board = new Board();
        currTurn = Piece.WHITE;
        movesPlayed = new ArrayList<Move>();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chessboard");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            frame.setSize(640, 640);
            frame.setResizable(false);  
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            Chessboard chessboard = new Chessboard(board);
            frame.add(chessboard);

            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
```

In the code above i used setSize to set it to `640, 640`. I added a listener to verify the size. but when i run the app, the size that gets printed (by my listener), is:

`Window size: 624x601`

I know this probably has to do with the window decorations. Can I somehow calculate the size I need to add to get the window size I really want?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stop trying to make the window the right size, instead, provide appropriate sizing hints from the content itself and then `pack` the window around the content.  "How" you do this will depend greatly on you overall implementation

Comment: Umm, im basically trying to create an 8x8 chess board with squares of sizes 80x80. So the sizes should be 640x640 obv... im kinda new to Swing in java, so can u explain more about what u just said or give a reference to a resource i can use?

Comment: Sure, but are you using components to generate that grid or custom painting?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, it depends.

`JFrame#pack` will "pack" the window decorations around the viewable content based on the "preferred" size of the content as determined by the layout manager API.

So, if you using some kind of custom component to generate the cells, then you will need to provide appropriate sizing hints, for example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new Board());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Board extends JPanel {
        public Board() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
            for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
                int cellIndex = (row % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 1;
                for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                    Cell cell = new Cell();
                    cell.setBackground((cellIndex % 2 == 0) ? Color.WHITE : Color.BLACK);
                    add(cell);
                    cellIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Cell extends JPanel {
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(80, 80);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this will allow the window to be resized and for the cells to become unevenly sized.  You could fix this by adding `frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());` before `frame.add(new Board());`, but also remember, components have a "minimum" size, so you might be surprised if you size the window smaller